# asp.net Login issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have a website  that contains  a login page the problem  is that website allows a limit of about 2 to three  users to login while the others will be forwarded  to the home page without refusing login  credentials  neither Log them in
And it shows no errors or warning
the only way to make user login is restarting the hosting server and it work for only few user and back to same problem

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="Cookie" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="true" path="/">
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what issue is. Check if this link helps: Troubleshoot Forms Authentication  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/910439/troubleshoot-forms-authentication

Comment: i found the issue it in report viewer  if i delete it login work fine any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I suggest you modify your question and include more info (Web.Config settings). You have something else here at play that's affecting the behavior you see. Also, I realize that English is probably not your first language (like mine). However, your question is a run-on sentence (one long sentence with no punctuation marks) and it's hard to understand. Better questions, will attract more replies.

Comment: try to run the failed request tracing in iis to get more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis.  also check the iis logs which status code and substatus code its logged when user redirect to the homepage.